# Unit tests for execution time (perfomance) decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, time, floating-point

I have a execution time (perfomance) decorator that calculates average execution time of given function and print results with `float` values:

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep

def benchmark_decorator(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        results = list()
        n_repeats = 3
        for i in range(n_repeats):
            time_start = perf_counter()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time_end = perf_counter()
            time_duration = time_end - time_start
            results.append(time_duration)
            print(f'>run {i+1} took {time_duration} seconds')
        avg_duration = sum(results) / n_repeats
        print(f'Took {avg_duration} seconds on average')
        return result
    
    return wrapper
```

How to test that this decorator makes the right calculations of average time?
For example, let's check this simple function:

```
@benchmark_decorator
def func(seconds):
    sleep(seconds)

func(1)
```

And we have this output:

```
>run 1 took 1.0005083000287414 seconds
>run 2 took 1.0000609999988228 seconds
>run 3 took 1.000284199952148 seconds
Took 1.0002844999932374 seconds on average
```

So I get a slightly different result every time and can't just assert this result with one number.
Also I can't just round this values with `.3f` for example because function can be very fast and we will get very low values of time:

```
@benchmark_decorator
def func():
    pass

func()
```

Gives this output:

```
>run 1 took 4.400033503770828e-06 seconds
>run 2 took 1.500011421740055e-06 seconds
>run 3 took 5.00003807246685e-07 seconds
Took 2.133349577585856e-06 seconds on average
```

And if we round this values with `.3f` we will get zeroes.
So how to test this slightly different times properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pytest`, you can capture the stdout with the [`capsys` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html), parse the average result from that and perform the rounding inside the test like so

```py
import pytest

@benchmark_decorator
def wrap_sleep(seconds):
    sleep(seconds)

def test_benchmark_decorator(capsys):
    wrap_sleep(1)
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    average = float(captured.out.rsplit(" ", 4)[1])
    # Rounding
    assert average == pytest.approx(1, abs=1e-3)
    # Relative 2% error
    assert average == pytest.approx(1, rel=0.02)
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but like I mention above - rounding it's not good practice, because we can get very different time values (depending of function), both very small and very large, and we can't use `abs=1e-3` everywhere.

Comment: If you want to check the performance of every function you test with this decorator, I think you need to parameterize the expected performance individually for each test. You could also use the relative approximation with `pytest.approx` if rounding is not working for your use case.